# Getting a DataRow from a ListView control

Tags: c#, .net, listview, datarow

I have a ListViewControl called list.  I need to grab the row from the list, and make it a DataRow.  I've never used ListViewControls, as I always just use DevExpress grids.  Is there a simple way to go about this I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

ListView controls are based on older technology that is not totally compatible with managed code. Use either a DataGridView for Windows Forms or a DataGrid for WPF.

It is also very worthwhile to learn about the Entity Framework. Learning about the Entity Framework will take time now but save a lot of time in the future.

Comment: I dont really have a choice which control is being used because the screen is already made and I'm just adding functionality to it.  Is there any way to go about this?